# Handling errors when saving multiple documents with mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am creating an API that can receive multiple documents.
My code calls Document#create using promises, as follows:

```
var body = [{url: "http://url1"}, {url: []}]; // example of a request payload
Image.create(body).then(function(images){
    // do something...
}).onReject(function(err) {
    // err is the object returned by the first problematic document
});
```

The model on the code above would reject the second document, since the `url` parameter isn't a String.

The problem is that when one of the documents fails a validation, only the first failure is sent to the failure function in the promise.

Also, I don't have access to any of the records that were successfully saved. I searched the docs and the tests on github, but couldn't find anything on the matter.

Is there a better way to handle this situation when creating multiple documents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is currently no way to get the records that were successful when passing an array to the Document#create method. Even the callback function doesn't pass them as parameters.

The way I managed to do what I wanted was by creating the resource object via `new` and then saving the object:

```
var body = [{url: "http://url1"}, {url: []}]; // example of a request payload
var images = [];
body.forEach(function(img) {
    var image = new Image(img);
    image.save(function(err) {
        images.push(err || image);
    });
});
```

Since I won't allow large numbers of records to be created at once, this solution worked. By the end of the execution, I have an array containing all records and also the error messages returned by the ones that failed.